# Java does not recognize a file when it begins with "file:/"

Tags: java, file, url

Java says a file does not exist when it is a valid file path, but begins with file:/. I could use substring to get rid of this, but I don't want to mess the URL up for other OS's. Is there a way to fix this issue? Normalizing the URL doesn't help.

Comment: How are you creating the java object representing the URL? Are you using java.io.File?

Comment: I say File f = new File(s), where s is this string representing the URL, passed in by a parameter.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: To get proper answers sooner [edit] your post and include [MCVE]

Comment: @Paul Actually, a valid file: URL must have either one slash or three slashes after the colon.  Two slashes introduces an authority (user, host, and port), which doesn’t make sense in a file: URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

java.io.File(String) is expecting an abstract pathname. That is "C:/somefile" or "/home/auser/somefile".

[java.io.File(URI)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File(java.net.URI)%20Constructor%20Doc) is what you want if you want it to be "file://". You can simply do `new File(new URI(filename));`

I recommend reading the [URI Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html) to understand the difference between an abstract pathname and a Uniform Resource Identifier

Answer (score 3):

```
URI uri = new URI("file:/Users/jb");
Path path = Paths.get(uri);
System.out.println("path = " + path); // prints /Users/jb
File file = path.toFile();
System.out.println("file = " + file); // prints /Users/jb
```

Answer (score 0):

File file = new File(new URL(s).toURI());